# How to upgrade magento 2.2.4 to 2.2.5 version?

Tags: magento2

How to upgrade magento 2.2.4 to latest version ie., 2.2.5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please use the command line to execute following commands in Magento installation root directory.

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5 --no-update
composer update

rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/cache/
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/page_cache/
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/generation/

bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
service varnish restart
```

For more details refer magento docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Comment: when I tried to upgrade I have one doubt

Comment: Authentication required (repo.magento.com):
      Username: admin
      Password:
user name, password means

Comment: You can able to get it from your Magento account https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html